# How can I display a variable when the user asks for it?

Tags: java, user-input

Basically, I want the user to input 'Average' or 'Sum' so I can then display the relevant one that was requested using System.out.println();

But how can I do this? (Apologies if this is really simple)

```
int SumChocolates = 0;
SumChocolates = (int) (data [0][7] + data [1][7] + data [2][7] + data [3][7]);

int AvgChocolates = 0;
AvgChocolates = (int) (SumChocolates / 4);
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/

Comment: Take the input with a scanner, and have a switch-case statement for the input provided.

Comment: [tag:eclipse] tag removed as the question has no bearing on this IDE.

Comment: @Pshemo You can't use console input in Eclipse. (The question was originally tagged Eclipse)

Comment: @mbomb007 Examples of this article are about reading from standard input stream of process (`System.in`), regardless if process was run with console (`java.exe`) or without console (`javaw.exe` like eclipse does).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Scanner` then use `Scanner.nextLine();` to get input from the user in the console.

Also, you may want to take a look at the standard naming schemas in Java

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in ); //Create a new Scanner
System.out.println("Would you like the average, or sum?");
String input = scan.nextLine(); //Get input from the user

int SumChocolates = 0; //Must declare out here, because Average case uses this
SumChocolates = (int)(data[0][7] + data[1][7] + data[2][7] + data[3][7]);

if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Sum")) {
    System.out.println("The Sum is: " + SumChocolates);
} else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Average")) {
    int AvgChocolates = 0;
    AvgChocolates = (int)(SumChocolates / 4);
    System.out.println("The average is: " + AvgChocolates);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = scanner.next();
```

Comment: better use `scanner.nextLine()`

Comment: Out of curiosity: why exactly? next() returns the next token entered by the user as String.

Comment: what if the user enter more than one token?

Answer (score 0):

Use a scanner. Depending on their input, display the output you want. Also, variables should be lowerCamelCase to comply with [Java coding standards](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.7-local-variable-names).

This checks to make sure they enter valid input before displaying a result.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
System.out.println("Would you like to see the Average, or the Sum?");

while (true) {
    input = s.nextLine();
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Average")) {
        System.out.println(avgChocolates);
        break;
    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Sum")) {
        System.out.println(sumChocolates);
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter 'Average' or 'Sum'.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (input == "Average")` [no No NO, not again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: you can't compare strings by "==" - use input.equals("Average")

Comment: Oh sorry. I've been programming in other languages lately. Thanks, for that.